# Shell script kill background process on quit

Tags: bash, kill, background-process

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ./cmd1&
exec ./cmd2
```

If I kill the script only `cmd2` is killed, `cmd1` keeps running.
Is it possible that both processes quit automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not do second `exec` (the first one is redundant, too) but leave the shell wait for it. killing the shell may kill the commands; if not - then:

```
    trap 'kill -15 $kids; exit 143' TERM
    cmd1 &
    kids=$!
    cmd2 &
    kids="$kids $!"
    wait
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me, but thank you for the answer (I'm on OS X, things are a little different here...)

Comment: tested on OS X - how do you kill?

Comment: I would like to run this in an application bundle. When I click on it, the dock icon keeps hopping forever, and all I can do is force quit it.

Comment: I belive `trap '...' EXIT` will suite better.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop, you can pass multiple PIDs to `kill`.